# Why would 139 bytes exhausts 33000000 bytes of memory

Tags: php, memory-management

I am running a query with PHP PDO that returns an associative array totalling 139 bytes in size.

When I go to assign the result to values in a `while()` loop it fails saying it exhausted the memory but that doesn't make sense. The attempted allocation is miniscule to what is available.

If I run this in a `foreach()` loop it works fine.

If I do `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` the page never loads. It seems like there is an infinite loop.

Is there something else that could cause this error to be thrown? What would cause a `while()` loop to go into an infinite loop when working with `while($rows = $stmt->fetchAll())`

Comment: It's incremental. So it tried to allocate 139 but that is the drop that fills the bucket. See if you can optimize your memory usage (de-reference things you don't need any more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->fetchAll()` returns an array like this:

```
array(
    array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Dave"),
    array("id"=>2,"name"=>"John")
)
```

Namely, an array of records.

Using `foreach` iterates through this array. Using `while` does not. Since your array always exists, `while` will always be true!

`foreach` is used most commonly, but you could do this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
while($row = array_shift($result)) {  ...  }
```

This works because the `$result` array will run out of rows, at which point the `while` will be false and end.

Comment: May I ask you to change this awful array_shift solution to the more familiar while(fetch())? Or even limit your suggestion to foreach?